# Unable to use WebRTC with different ISP provide

Tags: android, webrtc

I have use the below links. I am able to do video call only with same network WiFi or with same network operator. Can you please suggest some solutions for placing video call with different networks.

1. [WebRTC Smple](https://github.com/pauloouriques/android-native-video-chat)
2. [WebRTC Demo](https://github.com/linsir6/webRTC-android-demo-and-Server)

This is my setup. Connection configuration:

```
PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration rtcConfig = new PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration(signalingParameters.iceServers);
rtcConfig.iceTransportsType = PeerConnection.IceTransportsType.ALL;
rtcConfig.tcpCandidatePolicy = PeerConnection.TcpCandidatePolicy.DISABLED;
rtcConfig.bundlePolicy = PeerConnection.BundlePolicy.MAXBUNDLE;
rtcConfig.rtcpMuxPolicy = PeerConnection.RtcpMuxPolicy.REQUIRE;.
rtcConfig.keyType = PeerConnection.KeyType.ECDSA;
peerConnection = factory.createPeerConnection(signalingParameters.iceServers, pcConstraints, pcObserver);
```

And turn server is,

```
iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("turn:54.215.239.112:3478?transport=tcp", "******", "*******"));
```

Comment: did you add Turn Server?

Comment: Yes add but i it also not working with different network.

Comment: can you add the Turn server which i have given in my answer and try again?

Comment: i add both server still not working with different netwotk (WiFi + Jio)

Comment: I think the issue is with your Turn server, i had this issue before and was resolved by using TURN server, try this one ( http://numb.viagenie.ca/ ), make an account and get credential and username

Answer (score 1):

This will probably be because you need to add a TURN Server to the `iceServers` array in the following file after Line 285.

```
iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:23.21.150.121"));
iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"));
```

[See WebRtcClient.java](https://github.com/linsir6/webRTC-android-demo-and-Server/blob/9a8a3115193892b600189672c96a5d7213fd0087/Android/webrtc-client/src/main/java/fr/pchab/webrtcclient/WebRtcClient.java#L285)

The demo only uses STUN servers, however TURN Servers are used when connecting by STUN hasn't been successful and can cover scenarios such as traversing symmetric NATs.

It may be the case that your application has failed to find a way to connect to the remote peer using STUN and so will need to fallback to TURN. Because you have not specified a TURN server, connection fails.

Details on how to set up your own TURN Server:
[See coturn](https://github.com/coturn/coturn)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Turn server for making it work on different networks like this

```
iceServers.add(new org.webrtc.PeerConnection.IceServer("turn:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3478", "username", "credential"));
```

You can use [this](http://numb.viagenie.ca/) service for getting a Turn Server